# Turning each unique DataFrame column value into a dictionary key and populating dictionary with data from the DataFrame that corresponded with values

Tags: python, finance, trading

I have a data frame full of my recent trades. It is 7 columns across and 40ish columns down containing date time ticker price quantity side and to open/to close. I want to eventually create my own trading journal that will keep track of my open positions, closed positions, P/L, etc. In the DataFrame there are multiple occurrences of each ticker, for buys and sells. I want to make unique DataFrames that tack the open positions, can I create individual ticker DataFrames from the overarching DataFrame or do I have to go through a dictionary?

Comment: You might look at pandas `groupby`.  We don't have your exact layout, but it may be able to let you extract a single issue into a separate df.

Comment: This is helpful, but it is not letting me run a loop over each ticker group to create a separate DataFrame of all that tickers info. Any idea here?

Comment: You should be able to do things like `df1 = df[df.ticker == 'IBM']`.  I may have the axis order wrong; pandas is a bit unruly about that.